# Calculating an integration in terms of an exp

Tags: integration

Hi Does anyone can help solve the following integration?

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}exp(-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}-\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}})^2)dx$

The solution says we can turn the above terms into

$=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sqrt{2t}exp(-u^2)du$

But how? In case the brackets cause any confusion, I also attach a screenshot here. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: After letting $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}-\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}$ then $du=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2t}}$ and the limits of integration are the same.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you!! I feel so dumb now lol. Thanks